# Eclipse PDE Logging

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to send the exceptions of my plugin to the Error Log, but I don't want them to be shown in the Eclipse console. This is what I am doing.

First, I implemented ILogListener.

```java
public class MyILogListener implements ILogListener {

    @Override
    public void logging(IStatus status, String plugin) {
        System.out.println("logging: " + plugin);

    }

}
```

I have this sample Action to do the test.

```java
public void run(IAction action) {

    ILogListener iL = new MyILogListener();
    Platform.addLogListener(iL);

    Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle(test.Activator.PLUGIN_ID);
    ILog log = Platform.getLog(bundle);
    Object o = null;
    try {
        o.equals("sk");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.log(new Status(Status.ERROR, test.Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "test", e));


    }

}
```

The exception is written in the Error Log of the Eclipse aplication and this is shown in the console.

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.actions.SampleAction.run(SampleAction.java:52)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WWinPluginAction.runWithEvent(WWinPluginAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

logging: org.eclipse.core.runtime

You can see the MyILogListener is printing "org.eclipse.core.runtime", I thought it would print my plugin ID, which is "Test". Also, in my implementation I'm not writing anything to the log, but the exception appears in the Error Log. I only want to write the exception in the Error Log, and not show it in the console.

What I am doing wrong? I'm trying this with Eclipse 3.7.0 and 3.7.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Eclipse 3.7 documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/whatsNew/platform_isv_whatsnew.html):

> All eclipse logging APIs are now aggregated through the org.eclipse.equinox.log.Logger with the name org.eclipse.equinox.logger. All ILogListener instances will be notified of entries logged through this logger.

This means that by logging to a bundle's log a bunch of listeners will be notified, one of them being Eclipse [`StatusManager`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/statushandlers/StatusManager.html) which logs the status to error log.

If you only want to log to Eclipse error log (and Error Log view) then you should call one of `StatusManager.handle()` methods directly.