# How can I write in the "Error log" section in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

I want to write in the "Error log" section.
Any help please?

Comment: Question not understandable .

Comment: Any particular reason? Are you trying to write an Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to log messages from your Eclipse plugin? If yes, please see this [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_logging_facility%3F) entry.

Also see [Eclipse PDE Logging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8122787/276263)